# Why does returning snapshot.val() in a Promise when using Promise.all not work?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, es6-promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a Firebase Cloud Function and I'm trying to figure out how `Promise.all` works. In my code, I pass in an [array of database queries](https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/Robot-Scouter/blob/717c90264e077011ce35044b3955140e1741066c/firebase/functions/index.js#L50-L55) and I'm trying the [read the resulting array](https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/Robot-Scouter/blob/717c90264e077011ce35044b3955140e1741066c/firebase/functions/index.js#L57-L62), but I'm only getting garbage:

```
T {
  A: 
   P {
     k: Sb { Ka: [Function: vb], ba: [Object] },
     aa: P { k: [Object], aa: null, wb: [Object], Bb: '' },
     wb: Zc { ld: [Object], ac: [Object] },
     Bb: null },
  V: 
   R {
     u: 
      Gd {
        app: [Object],
        L: [Object],
        Ua: [Object],
        Sc: null,
        ca: [Object],
        td: 1,
        Qa: [Object],
        va: [Object],
        qg: [Object],
        jc: [Object],
        ee: [Object],
        md: [Object],
        ia: [Object],
        Xa: [Object],
        cd: 2,
        fe: null,
        K: [Object] },
     path: J { o: [Object], Y: 0 },
     m: 
      Df {
        xa: false,
        ka: false,
        Ib: false,
        na: false,
        Pb: false,
        oa: 0,
        kb: '',
        bc: null,
        xb: '',
        Zb: null,
        vb: '',
        g: Tc {} },
     Kc: false,
     then: undefined,
     catch: undefined },
  g: Tc {} }
```

I'm expecting a simple json:

```
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "number": 2521
    // And a few other fields
}
```

BTW, I watched [Jen's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc) so I know what I'm doing is wrong anyway; I just want to know why my existing code doesn't work. (I haven't tested it, but I believe the solution is to return the raw snapshots in my db query and then do the `.val()` call.)

Relevant code if the links disappear:

```
function mergeTeams(duplicates) {
    return Promise.all([
        admin.database().ref(someRef).once('value', (snap) => {
            return snap.val();
        }),
        admin.database().ref(someRef2).once('value', (snap) => {
            return snap.val();
        })
    ]).then(values => {
        console.log(values);

        const team1 = values[0];
        const team2 = values[1];
        console.log(team1);
        console.log(team2);
}
```

Comment: you haven't shown how you are using `Promise.all` - probably incorrectly (put relevant code in question)

Comment: Yes I did, click on the link called "array of database queries". Or click it here: https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/Robot-Scouter/blob/717c90264e077011ce35044b3955140e1741066c/firebase/functions/index.js#L50-L55

Comment: nah, relevant code should be in the question

Comment: I think you'll need to do something like `admin.database().ref(teamRef + duplicates.teamKey2).once('value').then(snap => snap.val())` - because, well, promises work that way

Comment: I updated the question with the code. Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: see, the way you are using a callback means that the value returned inside the callback has no bearing on anything (it's ignored)

Comment: The kind of output posted looks eerily like that in http://stackoverflow.com/q/43431330/5217142 - it may be of interest. Also, do you have a documentation reference for the `once` method taking two parameters?

Comment: @JaromandaX Nah, your solution didn't work either.

Comment: @Traktor53 I figured it out, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647534/why-does-returning-snapshot-val-in-a-promise-when-using-promise-all-not-work/43647752#43647752

Comment: oh well, I have no clue how firebase works - at least I got you on the right track

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, definitely thanks! (I upvoted your comment)

Comment: FYI we have a recent video on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc

Answer (score 1):

So, here's the code that works (and the explanation below):

```
return Promise.all([
    admin.database().ref(teamRef + duplicates.teamKey1).once('value'),
    admin.database().ref(teamRef + duplicates.teamKey2).once('value')
]).then(values => {
    const team1 = values[0].val();
    const team2 = values[1].val();

    console.log(team1);
    console.log(team2);
});
```

The reason it works is because I've always getting the promises in the `values` array even though I didn't know it. Here's what `Promise.all` returns: an array with the raw result of the promises passed in. When I was returning stuff inside the [success callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#once), that didn't actually do anything because it wasn't part of the promise; I was just returning random stuff to an empty void. And when I was printing the teams, I was actually logging the Firebase `Snapshot` object instead of the `.val()`.

Comment: "I guess it's a JS thing" may be incorrect. Do you have a documentation reference describing how `once` makes use of two parameters?

Comment: @Traktor53 Oh true. That would make way more sense, let me look into it.

Comment: @Traktor53 Thanks, I think I really get it now! Yeah, when I was returning stuff, it was in the success callback for Firebase which has nothing to do with the JS `Promise`.

Comment: Great. FYI, per http://stackoverflow.com/q/43431330/5217142 you may have been logging the snapshot object itself - a promise can not be **fulfilled** with a promise, so there won't be one in the `values` array.

Comment: @Traktor53 Yeah, I realized that and I updated my answer. Thanks anyway!